# Secondary hard disk does not auto-mount

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, automount

I have a secondary hard disk (8 TB, ext4) that does not auto-mount on OS startup despite "auto-mount" being set to "on" within the "Mount Options" of the "Disks" utility application.

How do I enable the auto-mount option to have this effect?

I am running 14.04. The disk is housed within a trayless removable rack and is present prior to powering the system. There is no problem using the disk once I have mounted it manually.

===

Output of `sudo blkid;cat /etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7c101c3e-7f80-4744-aa34-7a111a5c16a4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="022e4360-27be-4f6e-909a-e10a91ee8046" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="data" UUID="4270461f-dacc-4ea1-846b-b79b19870ae2" TYPE="ext4" 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7c101c3e-7f80-4744-aa34-7a111a5c16a4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=022e4360-27be-4f6e-909a-e10a91ee8046 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Open terminal and run  command: `sudo blkid;cat /etc/fstab`. Post output

Comment: Also, you might try following this tutorial.http://docs.system76.com/articles/extraDrive It is posted by System76, but is not specific to their machines. You might find some helpful information or some steps that you missed

Comment: @Serg: I've updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your `/etc/fstab` file suggest that only two block devices get mounted - your Ubuntu partition, `/dev/sda1` and your memory swap partition, `/dev/sda5` , both of which are on the same disk `/dev/sda`

What you need to do to automount the secondary hard disk is to edit the `/etc/fstab` in accordance with output of `blkid` (the first 3 lines).

Run `pkexec gedit /etc/fstab` in terminal, to edit that file with super-user privilege. Add the following line:

```
UUID=4270461f-dacc-4ea1-846b-b79b19870ae2 /media/SECONDARY ext4 noatime,nodiratime,user=1000,rw 0 0
```

Save and exit the gedit text editor

Note, you should create `/media/SECONDARY` folder before reboot with `sudo mkdir /media/SECONDARY`. SECONDARY doesn't have to be the name, you can change it to whatever you want, but keep in mind to change it in `/etc/fstab` as well.

Note also the option `user=1000` . Assuming you are the only user on your system, 1000 is default for first user ever created, hence that option. Verify your user id with `id -u` command. Change accrodingly

As for your original issue, I am not familiar with Ubuntu's disks utility, so I don't know possible reason for it not working. I would assume it performs the same task as editing `/etc/fstab` manually.